# System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfService/MathOpeationService/

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I am trying to create wcf service and want to host on windows service.and install that service on windows.

so what I did I add wcf service library then built and run. after that its does successfully.

but when I create anther WCF appilcation so shows me this error= System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException.

SO how can I solve this issues please help to resolve this issue.

I install InstallUtil.exe but process not start on windows.

I want to host my WCF service on window and consume that service on my client application

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you use WCF service application Template to create WCF service.
The error mainly indicates that the http address is already in use, we could change the port number and try it again.
At last, we had better use administrator account to install/run the windows service since the system layer driver (http.sys) manages the machine port. We could also use the below command to reverse the URL for the account runs the service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.